# Deleting a cell from a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I've programmed a simple UITableView list that shows the "Delete" button when the user swipes to the right.

When the red "Delete" button slides in from the right, the main text of the cell also momentarily slides to the left, before quickly snapping back to where it should be. I've noticed this strange little "animation" doesn't occur in apps like Contacts or Messages.

It seems to be something to do with the resizing of the cell. Is there a simple setting that I'm missing?

Comment: Is this a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass, or just a standard cell?

Comment: I'm quite new to it, but it was created via storyboard and populated with the method found at this link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: Unless you're using custom cells, it's worthwhile sticking to the built in styles, they're explained here: [UITableView HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW42)